# Как получить код из Конструктора карт для использования в JS API?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Создал карту через конструктор, добавил несколько объектов, всё хорошо, но оказалось что для отображения на мобильных устройствах мне не хватает кнопки "Определение местоположения".

Почитав тут, понял, что к сожалению придется переделывать карту вручную и настройками JS включать эту кнопку. Кстати, непонятно почему по умолчанию её нет малых экранах, ведь именно там она и нужна в первую очередь. Ну да ладно.

Так как в JS не силен, прошу помощи - подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли как-то параметры моих объектов из конструктора (это иконка, название, содержимое, координаты) получить в виде корректного кода для использования файле JS? Ладно если автоматически не получится "связать" карту из конструктора карт и вручную созданную карту, то где хотя бы посмотреть код, который делает конструктор карт?

Или может быть есть еще какой-то способ просто добавить возможность "определить местоположение" на своей карте, созданной при помощи Конструктора.

Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Карта размера `width=320&height=240` имеет кнопку "Определение местоположения" http://jsfiddle.net/893cfogL/ . Картой меньшего размера неудобно пользоваться, поэтому кнопок там нет. Может быть просто увеличить размер, чтобы кнопки появились?
2. Если вас не устраивает вариант 1, то можно просто экспортировать объекты как это написано в документации https://yandex.ru/support/maps-builder/concept/markers_3.html и потом добавить на карту, как это показано в примере: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager_geojson